# openpyxl after load and save list index out of range(python)

Tags: python, openpyxl

I use openpyxl to work with excel documents in python. After opening and saving a file I cant open it in a file manager, it's broken.

```
workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook(path_to_tmp_xlsm)
workbook.save(path_to_tmp_xlsm)
print(path_to_tmp_xlsm)
```

my error:

```
list index out of range
```

ps This script works fine in Windows, but under Linux I have this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/alex/projects/bokapi/Main.py", line 11, in <module>
    class Main:
  File "/home/alex/projects/bokapi/Main.py", line 12, in Main
    EmailsDriveWorker()
  File "/home/alex/projects/bokapi/app/EmailDriveWorker.py", line 33, in __init__
    self.log_manager.save_all_companies_inf_log_to_gd()
  File "/home/alex/projects/bokapi/app/EmailDriveWorker.py", line 202, in save_all_companies_inf_log_to_gd
    path_to_xlsx = self.xmsl_box.update_log_file(log_list=logs, file=self.file)
  File "/home/alex/projects/bokapi/xmsl/XmslBox.py", line 172, in update_log_file
    workbook.save(path_to_tmp_xlsm)
  File "/home/alex/projects/bokapi/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/openpyxl/workbook/workbook.py", line 367, in save
    save_workbook(self, filename)
  File "/home/alex/projects/bokapi/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/openpyxl/writer/excel.py", line 284, in save_workbook
    writer.save(filename)
  File "/home/alex/projects/bokapi/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/openpyxl/writer/excel.py", line 266, in save
    self.write_data()
  File "/home/alex/projects/bokapi/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/openpyxl/writer/excel.py", line 95, in write_data
    archive.writestr(ARC_WORKBOOK, write_workbook(self.workbook))
  File "/home/alex/projects/bokapi/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/openpyxl/writer/workbook.py", line 95, in write_workbook
    wb.views[0].activeTab = active
IndexError: list index out of range

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: posting full stack trace would be helpful

Comment: As this is an `.xlsm` file, I suggest you can try adding the parameter `keep_vba=True` to `load_workbook()`.

Comment: @Marat thanks for comment, i have not full stack trace. I only open xlsx file and save it. And it all, after this, this xlsx file doesnt open

Comment: @MartinEvans thks for comment, i try add `workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook(path_to_tmp_xlsm, keep_vba=True)` and it not work. I have same error

Comment: @Piinthesky thanks for comment. I have `minimal`(code, description)  full traceback i have not. I only opne xlsx file and save it, and it all.  After this my file not open, its brouken. About full traceback, if i set `print(path_to_tmp_xlsm)` it output `list index out of range`

Comment: "list index out of range" looks like a Python exception, which usually comes with a bunch of additional information, aka stacktrace. Anyway, more details about the error is needed

Comment: @Marat this code i add in try except block. And in the line `workbook.save(path_to_tmp_xlsm)` i have exception `list index out of range`

Comment: @Marat sorry, today i lot of work time. I add Traceback

Comment: @MartinEvans sorry I add Traceback

Comment: @Piinthesky i update my question. Sorry

Comment: Are you able to put a cut down version of the file onto something like [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/) and give us a link to test with?

Comment: @MartinEvans yes, i pasted code https://pastebin.com/WVkjcMEA

Comment: If there is a difference between OSes then it's almost certainly a version problem. Check you have the same version openpyxl on both systems.

Comment: Sorry, I meant the `.xlsx` file that is causing the problem

Comment: @MartinEvans i upload file in this link https://files.fm/u/5r7ehrhg

Comment: I cannot reproduce the issue with openpyxl 2.5.0 (Linux). What version do you use? (`openpyxl.__version__`)

Comment: I'm hitting this exact problem. I have a program that works fine with one file, crashes with another. I have determined that when openpyxl loads the problem file, `wb.views()` is an empty list (instead of a list with length 1 as usual.) Can't yet say why/when this happens, or how to work around it. `openpyxl 2.5.1` on OS X (Python 3.6.4).

Answer (score 3):

You (and I) seem to have run into this bug: [Saving workbook gives IndexError on wb.views](https://bitbucket.org/openpyxl/openpyxl/issues/985/saving-workbook-gives-indexerror-on). (Also reported [here](https://bitbucket.org/openpyxl/openpyxl/issues/283/load_workbook-error-list-index-out-of), but that one was closed because the OP couldn't reproduce.) The good news is that this bug was fixed... two weeks ago. I don't know when it'll land in the distributed version of openpyxl, but in the meantime you can work around the bug like this:

```
wb = load_workbook("name.xlsx")
# Fix malformed workbook bug (gag)  
if not wb.views:
    wb.views.append(openpyxl.workbook.views.BookView())
```

I have verified that the error occurs when `wb.views` is an empty list. This just adds a new view with default values, and Excel seems to like it fine.

PS. It seems that some files just don't store a view (or if they do, `openpyxl` can't parse it.) In my case the same script, on the same computer (OS X), works on one doc and fails on another. Both were last edited with Excel, but the problem file was previously written with OpenOffice; perhaps that's relevant.